# Hosting WCF WF in IIS7 (WF4.0)

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

I have a workflow created inside the WCF and now i want to host it in IIS. I am not sure how exactly to do it, can anybody provide me any pointers to some links or study material for doing this?

Comment: Check out this [Channel9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-Services-with-Dave-Cliffe/) on hosting workflow services in IIS

Answer (score 1):

Here is a walkthrough: http://blog.newagesolution.net/2008/06/how-to-create-wf-as-wcf-service-hosted.html